# MVC DateTime Not Converting

Tags: c#, datetime, cultureinfo

I want them all DateTime format to be this way: `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss`

I try this:

```
DateTime time= aModel.time; //{13.01.2018 08:30:00}
string formatcurrenttime = String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss}", time);
DateTime formattedTime = Convert.ToDateTime(formatcurrenttime);
```

But given error, not work. Exception:

> The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

I try this:

```
CultureInfo cultureinfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
DateTime time= aModel.time; //{13.01.2018 08:30:00}
string formatcurrenttime = String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss}", time);
DateTime formattedTime = DateTime.Parse(formatcurrenttime2, cultureinfo);
```

Given error.

I try this:

```
DateTime formattedTime = DateTime.Parse(formatcurrenttime, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

but again give error.

What was wrong?

Note: The first code are work yesterday. Not work today. Change my VDS hosting IP address by hosting company. I suspect to ASP.NET Culture or UI Culture settings.

Comment: Why are you converting it back into a datetime after setting the string format?

Comment: Which error , Provide error detail also.

Comment: Your code is working here without errors. I can convert back and forth. What error do you get?

Comment: The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: Note: The first code are work yesterday. Not work today. Change my VDS hosting IP address by hosting company. I suspect to ASP.NET Culture or UI Culture settings.

Comment: If `aModel.time` is DateTime, how you mentioned it is `{13.01.2018 08:30:00}` which is not correct format as datetime string?

Comment: I want this datetime result: 01.13.2018 08:30:00

Comment: @GeomatikMühendisi see my answer is that you need?

Comment: A `DateTime` object has *no format*.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass string format with `dot` in it, 
as you said in comments that you want a format like `01.13.2018 08:30:00` then below code works.
so as workaround you can do something like:

```
string stringTime = time.ToString("MM'.'dd'.'yyyy' 'HH':'mm':'ss");
```

or

```
string stringTime = time.ToString("MM.dd.yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

then if you want to pass the invariant culture:

```
string stringTime = time.ToString("MM.dd.yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```